# Delete last Sqlite row that have same certain name value

Tags: node.js, sqlite

How can I write a function that will delete just one row (ideally the last one) that has a given name (which may not be unique).

I have tried using row count, limits, and my own built in function (below). None of these have worked.

```
app.delete('/FamilyMember/:db', (req, res) => {
  let db = openDB("ClientsDatabases/"+req.params.db);
  let ids = [];
  db.serialize(()=>{
    db.each('select * from family', (err, row)=> {
      if (row.name == req.body.name) {
        ids.push(row.id);
      }
    })
    db.run("DELETE FROM family WHERE id = ?",ids[ids.length-1], (err)=> {
      console.log("Here is the err "+err);
      if (!err) console.log('Succesful @ deleting', req.body.name);
    });
  })
  res.send();
}, () => {
  db.close();
})
```

My expected output is for only one row with the given name to be deleted, but the table doesn't change and no errors are caught.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you've got single quotes (`'`) around your `?` parameter in your call to [`Statement#run`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statementrunparam--callback)? Nothing in the [API documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) suggests that this is correct practice, could be an explanation as to why your query is mangled to the point where it doesn't delete anything, but also doesn't throw an error. I'd expect your call to `.run()` to look something more like the below:

```
db.run("DELETE FROM family WHERE id = ?",ids[ids.length-1], (err)=> {
    console.log("Here is the err "+err);
    if (!err) console.log('Succesful @ deleting', req.body.name);
});
```

---

You may alternatively be interested in simplifying your queries into a single statement that will grab the maximum `id` (provided the `id` is incremented each time) and delete that record:

```
db.run("DELETE FROM family WHERE id = MAX(id)", (err)=> {
    console.log("Here is the err "+err);
    if (!err) console.log('Succesful @ deleting', req.body.name);
});
```

This eliminates the need to load all the contents of `family` first just to grab a single `id` from it.